# R: how to use symbols as a FUN for apply?

Tags: r, function, sum, apply, cartesian-product

In R's documentation for apply, it says:

FUN: the function to be applied: see ‘Details’. In the case of functions like +, %*%, etc., the function name must be backquoted or quoted.

I don't understand the latter half the sentence.

When I do

```
     matrix1 = matrix(rnorm(3*4), 3, 4)
     apply(matrix1, 1, "+")
```

I get the transpose of the matrix

And when I do

```
     apply(matrix, 1, "%*%")
```

I get an error.

I'm trying to get the row-wise sum and product of this matrix.

Also, if that's not what the documentation is talking about, what do does + and %*% supposed to do when supplied as the FUN argument of apply?

Comment: Note that the first `apply` returns a vector and in R that means a **column** vector. As for the multiply, you need two operands, like in `apply(matrix1, 1, "%*%", t(matrix1))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I tried `apply(matrix1, 1, "%*%", t(matrix1))` I got an error. What is this supposed to do?

Comment: It multiplies each row of `matrix1` with its transpose. It was meant as an example of making `apply` work here. You need to tell us the output you are expecting.

Comment: @RuiBarradas got it! I was trying to get the row-wise sum and row-wise product of the matrix and also understand what the documentation meant, but this answers it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 matrix1 = matrix(rnorm(3*4), 3, 4)
 apply(matrix1, 1, "+")
```

Does something like the transpose because it supplies rows of the matrix1 object one by one and returns the values of each operation as columns. If you had on the other hand specified:

```
 apply(matrix1, 2, "+")
```

There would not have been the appearance of transposition because apply always returns its values as a column-major result.

In the second instance, you didn't give a second argument to the "`%*%`" operator. The "+" operator can be either unary or binary but the "`%*%`" operator is always binary. (It doesn't really make a lot of sense to use "`%*%`" with `apply` and a single dimension since "`%*%`" is really designed as a standalone operator. If you want the row-wise sum then just use:

```
 rowSums(matrix1)
```

But you could have used the slower:

```
  apply(matrix1, 1, sum)
```

For product use:

```
  apply(matrix1, 1, prod)
```

Neither + nor `%*%` are designed to collapse their arguments into a single value in contrast to `sum` and prod which are so designed.

Reply to comment. The `%*%` operator performs the "matrix multiply" operation. The i-columns of the first argument are multiplied by the J-rows and summed to deliver the i-j element of a new matrix. Many mathematical operations with statistical or physical meaning which would otherwise require a double for-loop can be accomplished by matrix-multiply. Let's imagine your matrix was a bunch of data values and you wanted to come up with a prediction for each row based on a model with three coefficients equal to say, c(5,6,7):

```
  c(5,6,7)  %*% matrix1
#         [,1]     [,2]    [,3]      [,4]
#[1,] 2.047344 10.02339 1.73618 0.7223964
```

Comment: can you explain what %*% is supposed to do? Or give an example of how to use it?

Comment: @Amazonian ``%*%`` performs matrix multiplication. See the help for and examples of the function via `?\`%*%\``

Comment: @42 When I came across the post I didn't anything explaining what `%*%` did, so wanted to clarify that to the OP. If your edit was there when I made my comment, then I must have missed it, and my apologies.